# Masonry - imagesLoaded - Not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-masonry, imagesloaded

`Masonry` and `imagesLoaded` should be loaded and work correctly. A similar site has been made, and there it works correctly. I have no idea where my problem is, so I am hoping that you maybe see the problem. There should be something missing.

In Chrome Inspect I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).imagesLoaded is not a function
```

By what I have understood this means that `.imagesLoaded` and `Masonry` should be correctly loaded? Else I would have recieved the error `$container.imagesLoaded is not a function` ?

**What I have tried**

- Checking if jquery-2.1.4.min.js is properly loaded
- Changing the order of when the jquery is loaded
- Searching online
- Searching for errors within the jquery

**Header**

```
<script src="http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/collection.js"></script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="masonry-container" class="row nomargin">
         <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                   <!--- Content --->
              </div>
              <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                   <!--- Content --->
              </div>
              <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                   <!--- Content --->
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="item col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
              <!--- Content --->
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Footer**

```
<script src="http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/imagesloaded.js"></script>

<script>
  $('#masonry-container').imagesLoaded( function(){
    $('#masonry-container').masonry({
     itemSelector: '.item',
     isAnimated: true,
     isFitWidth: true
    });
  });
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#masonry-container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isAnimated: true
    }, 'reload');
});
</script>
```

[The page can be found here.](http://www.vekvemedia.no/aktuelt/)

[A similar page where it works](http://roonabegum.no)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you have a Javascript conflict. To solve this issue you can putting jQuery Into No-Conflict Mode. Check out the jQuery [noConflict](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) function.

So try this :

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
 $('#masonry-container').imagesLoaded( function(){
    $('#masonry-container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isAnimated: true,
        isFitWidth: true
    });
 });

 $(window).resize(function() {
    $('#masonry-container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isAnimated: true
    }, 'reload');
 });
});
```

Comment: Can't see why you got a downvote from a user, because that solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome @Olen. I don't understand either for the downvote.