# .imagesLoaded is not a function in masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

My code is

```
var ssMasonryFolio = function () {
  var containerBricks = $('.masonry');
  containerBricks.imagesLoaded(function () {
      containerBricks.masonry({
          itemSelector: '.masonry__brick',
          resize: true
      });
  });
};
```

it gives error on imagesLoaded function

[image]

Comment: You're declaring `containerBricks` as a `DOM Element` without a `imagesLoaded function` beforehand. Also can you update the question with your given html and css at hand?

Comment: imagesLoaded is masonry function

Comment: Use `jQuery.noConflict()` See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899931/masonry-imagesloaded-not-a-function

Comment: i tried :)........

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imagesloaded is actually not a masonry function. 
It is a separate script, as described [here](https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#imagesloaded). You need to [download it](https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js) and load it before masonry.